# Printing a specific column using regex in Python 3

Tags: python, regex

I have a line which looks like this:

```
line = "A1   33        #_ABCDBDBBD_#        A8310810        _AJFA_AS_A__SA"
```

I want to extract fourth column from this line using re.search in python.

Currently I'm using

```
re.search(r"\s+([A-F0-9])+\s", line).group()
```

This prints `33`

Instead I'm expecting it to print `33 A8310810`

And then later extract the second element from this using `group(2)`.

What is my mistake? How do I extract the fourth column?

Comment: 33 A8... isn't the 4th column, it's the 2nd and 4th together. What do you actually need?

Comment: Your regex has only one group, so `group(2)` can't work.

Comment: Maybe you need [`re.findall(r"(?<=\s)[A-F0-9]+(?!\S)", line)`](http://ideone.com/Fhs3Io) => `['33', 'A8310810']`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's an elegant solution.

Comment: Almost looks like you should be using `line[5:15].rstrip() + ' ' + line[36:52].rstrip()`... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match multiple columns, it would be simpler to split by whitespace than match on content.

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "A1 33 #ABCDBDBBD# A8310810 _AJFA_AS_A__SA"
>>> cols = re.split('[\s]+', line)
>>> cols
['A1', '33', '#ABCDBDBBD#', 'A8310810', '_AJFA_AS_A__SA']
>>> cols[1]
'33'
>>> cols[3]
'A8310810'
```

---

You can also use `line.split()`:

```
>>> line.split()
['A1', '33', '#_ABCDBDBBD_#', 'A8310810', '_AJFA_AS_A__SA']
```

---

Here's another way using `re.match` to get your groups.

```
>>> m = re.match('^([\S]+)[\s]+([\S]+)[\s]+([\S]+)[\s]+([\S]+)[\s]+([\S]+)$', line)
>>> print(m.groups())
('A1', '33', '#_ABCDBDBBD_#', 'A8310810', '_AJFA_AS_A__SA') 
>>> m.group(2)
'33'
>>> m.group(4)
'A8310810'
```

Comment: `line.split()` will do the same thing, and also handle whitespace at the beginning or end of string correctly.

Comment: @interjay I was under the misconception that didn't work. Just tried it and it does. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I've used split and got the result. But I want to get it to work with re.search. Any solution ?

Comment: I want the 4th column using re.search

Comment: @user3017223 I've added a 3rd way using regex matching.

Comment: It looks like a fixed length file to me... so it may be possible it can't be split by a space looking regex if the boundaries run into each other... but again - not sure unless @user3017223 clarifies that...

Comment: @JonClements Yep, for sundry reasons, a simple split would've been better... but, OP's needs I guess...

Comment: @Coldspeed or what they're really after is the comment on their Q - who knows for sure :)

Comment: You should consider turning that comment into an answer. ;]

Answer (score 0):

You may fix your pattern by moving the plus quantifier into the group to quantify the character class, turning the last whitespace into a nonconsuming pattern  and use `re.findall`.

```
import re

line = "A1   33        #_ABCDBDBBD_#        A8310810        _AJFA_AS_A__SA"

print(re.findall(r"\s([A-F0-9]+)(?!\S)", line))
# => ['33', 'A8310810']
```

See the [Python 3 demo](http://ideone.com/Vmt74z).

Comment: I will add pattern description when I'm home.